# Mobiscroll custom wheel leading 0 required for single digit numbers

Tags: mobiscroll

I am using mobiscroll 2.0 and making 2 custom wheels one having numbers 0 to 23 and other having numbers 0 to 99 i want that the single digit numbers that is form 0 to 9 should have a leading 0 in front of them. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this demo:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/S5p6j/1/
```

You have to define custom wheels.

```
<input ID="mobiscroll" />
$(function(){
    var whl1 = {'0':'0',
                '1':'1', 
                '2':'3',
                '4':'4', 
                '5':'5'              
                };

    var whl2 = {'11':'11',
                '12':'12', 
                '13':'13',
                '14':'14', 
                '15':'15'};

    var wheel = [{},{}];

    wheel[0]['Wheel1'] = whl1;
    wheel[1]['Wheel2'] = whl2;

    $('#mobiscroll').scroller({
        wheels: wheel
    });    
});
```